# Unable to compile " unresolved reference: coroutines "

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I unable to compile my project, which i'm not sure why but i'm getting this error "unresolved reference: coroutines" / "unresolved reference: scope"

it was working before as i was on java8 but after mishandling on dependency, i endup deleting java8 and now i'm on java11. i cant seem to compile my project anymore.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following to the dependencies of your build.gradle module:app

```
api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
```

do you have?

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: yup it is added. Both kotlinx-coroutines-core and kotlinx-coroutines-android. still the same result.